# Does it refer to 'an event' in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ***it*** in the passage refer to ***an event***, or ***their own memory***?

> Finkenauer and Rimé investigated the memory of the unexpected death of
> Belgium’s King Baudouin in 1993 in a large sample of Belgian citizens.
> The data revealed that the news of the king’s death had been widely
> socially shared. By talking about the event, people gradually
> constructed a social narrative and a collective memory of the
> emotional event. At the same time, they consolidated ***their own
> memory of the personal circumstances in which the event took place***,
> an effect known as “flashbulb memory.” The more ***an event*** is
> socially shared, the more ***it*** will be fixed in people’s minds.
> Social sharing may in this way help to counteract some natural
> tendency people may have. Naturally, people should be driven to
> “forget” undesirable events. Thus, someone who just heard a piece of
> bad news often tends initially to deny what happened.The repetitive
> social sharing of the bad news contributes to realism.

[Cyberemotions: Collective Emotions in Cyberspace](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=yP5RDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=At%20the%20same%20time,%20they%20consolidated%20their%20own%20memory%20of%20the%20personal%20circumstances%20in%20which%20the%20event%20took%20place,%20an%20effect%20known%20as%20%E2%80%9Cflashbulb%20memory.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=j9XOBIeJpG&sig=ACfU3U1Tmv5aj0EpF9xWxtRMwpnEgjTxsg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9ge6e1sTrAhUQxYsBHdscDSgQ6AEwCnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=At%20the%20same%20time%2C%20they%20consolidated%20their%20own%20memory%20of%20the%20personal%20circumstances%20in%20which%20the%20event%20took%20place%2C%20an%20effect%20known%20as%20%E2%80%9Cflashbulb%20memory.%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The "it" you highlighted in the question almost certainly refers to "an event".

The object "their own memory" is the previous sentence is not proximal enough to that "it", and the parallel construction "The more _____ ...,  the more **it**...." also implies that the blank is the location of the referent.